# Is there a way with help of regex to make sure a string contains at least N digits, M upper case letters, R special characters?

Tags: regex

Also the string must be more than 8 and less than 30 characters long.
For example, need make sure the string (password) has at least 2 digits, 3 upper case letters and 4 special (like #$%^, etc) characters

Comment: you can do that with massive use of positive lookaheads, but i guess this is not the best way to do it

Comment: @nozzleman I've tried to do that for couple hours, but failed. Why is it a bad way?

Comment: @nozzleman, please, explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with one regex using only positive lookaheads:

```
(?=(.*\d.*){2,})(?=(.*[A-Z].*){3,})(?=(.*[^a-zA-Z\d\s].*){4,})(?=.{8,30})
```

### Explanation

This Regex makes use of multiple positive lookaheads (the `(?=)`-parts) to check if the cursor-position is followed by what the expression within the lookahead states. Every lookahead covers one of your conditions...

1. `(?=(.*\d.*){2,})` Two or more digits at random places
2. `(?=(.*[A-Z].*){3,})` Three or more uppercase letters at random places
3. `(?=(.*[^a-zA-Z\d\s].*){4,})`Four or more "special" charactes (with special meaning, no letter, no digit, no whitespace)
4. `(?=.{8,30})` 8 to 30 characters alltogether

See this [in action at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/AFjZdC/2)

### The Downsides

I guess there are better approaches on  solving this problem. What interesting here is that the overall regex cannot produce matches other than an empty string (`''`) beacause it only covers what follows a cursor position. So basically is says: *Is there any position in the string which is followed by a text part wich fullfills all of those conditions*. But it doesn't actually search for matches. The capturing groups within the lookahead of cource produce their own matches, but the first one will always be an empty string at best.

```js
var text = "!1#A$2B?C";
var regex = /(?=(.*\d.*){2,})(?=(.*[A-Z].*){3,})(?=(.*[^a-zA-Z\d\s].*){4,})(?=.{8,30})/;

var res  = regex.test(text);
var matches = text.match(regex)

alert(res ? "matches" : "doesn't match");
alert(matches.length > 0 ? "has matches" : "has no matches");

for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    alert("match[i] = '" + matches[i] + "'");
}
```